# Code Igniter not sending email using SMTP

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp

I'm already set the config like this

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp', 
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => '*****@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '****'
        );
```

but I can't send that email... It show error like this...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1673
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
```

And many other errors...

Comment: What are the "many other errors"?

Comment: It seems like PHP is not configured to work with SSL

Comment: Does your PHP installation include: OpenSSL? Do a `phpinfo();` to find out please.

Comment: @nulluserexception : A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1839

Comment: @peehaa : i dont know anything about it...how do i find phpinfo();??

Comment: @marol: just enter `phpinfo();` in a php file and look at the ouput. However since you get an error you should look into that first! Is the webservice allowed to write to a file at the location the error is bringing up?

Comment: hmmm....sorry PeeHaa...i'm not good enough in this problem...hehehehe
but now i've succeed send that email...the print_debugger show nothing..but i can view any email come into my inbox...how is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

First try this code:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '*****@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '****'
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);

// Other stuff about to,from,subject...

$result = $this->email->send();
```

If it's not working, check your php.ini file. Change this line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```